# Unable to figure out general equation of a percent increase & decrease

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, exponential-function

I've been doing a small coding project, and I've been having trouble figuring out mathematically the exact amount of increases and decreases of percentages I can do within a 'budget'.

For my specific issue, I have a budget of 0.05. Each decrease uses 0.002, and each increase uses 0.004.
I also have an initial value that I want to keep ultimately equal, while causing the largest possible decrease & increase. However, each decrease multiplies the value by $1-a$ , and each increase increases the value by $1+b$. Both $a$ and $b$ are variable inputs, but are within the bounds of $1\ge a\ge 0$ and $1\ge b\ge 0$.

Originally, I got this system of equations, where $n$ is the percentage left after all decreases, and $m$ is the percentage gained by all increases:
$$.002x+.004y=.05$$
$$n=(1-a)^x$$
$$m=(1+b)^y$$
$$1+m=n^{-1}$$

So far, I've gotten to this system of equations:
$$x=25-2y$$
$$1+(1+b)^y=(1-a)^{2y-25}$$
But, I can't figure out how to isolate y in the second equation.

Any help (or pointers on how to format questions better) is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I read the description correctly, should it instead be $m=n^{-1}$ i.e. $(1+b)^y (1-a)^x = 1$?

Comment: Looking back at the documentation I was using, yeah that seems to be the case. I thought it was initial value + (initial value * overall increase), but apparently it's just initial value * overall increase.

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered in a comment, I mistakenly thought that the percent increase was $initial+(initial*m)$, when it was actually $initial*m$. The system is then easily solvable with $log$.

Kudos to peterwhy.